# If within an if statement Java

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble inserting an if statement within an if statement. When the first 'if condition' is met, it still utilises the 'else' statement. Is there a way I can rewrite my code so that the 'else' statement is not being utilised. I thought that if the first 'if condition' was met then it would not check the else statement. I know I could use a switch statement, but I wanted to compare and contrast the uses of switch and if statement to gain a better understanding of Java. Below is my code. Thanks

```
    int age = 0;

    if (age == 0)
    {
        {System.out.println("You can crawl");}
        if (age == 1) {
            System.out.println("You can talk");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You can walk");
        }
    }
```

console:
You can crawl
You can walk

Comment: Some proper formatting might help. You’re checking whether `age` is `1` only when it’s `0`.

Comment: I would advice you to use an IDE (e.g. IntelliJ, netbeans, eclipse) so that you have some form of code structure as your code style there is absolutely horrendous and will make it harder for you to read or understand what is happening.

Comment: If you indent your code properly, you will see that you get in the `if (age == 0)`, and then you check `if (age == 1)` or `else`. So you can see that everything that is happening is logical.

Answer (score 5):

What may be currently happening is that the `age == 0` condition is firing true, but then, because of the way you structured the code, the `else` condition is also firing, as a predicate of the entirely separate `if` condition checking `age == 1`.  The solution is simple, connect everything via `if ... else if ... else` logic:

```
if (age == 0) {
    System.out.println("You can crawl");
}
else if (age == 1) {
    System.out.println("You can talk");
}
else {
    System.out.println("You can walk");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

First of all, if you want exclusive `if`s, you can branch them within a series of `else if` statements, i.e.:

```
if (age == 0) {
    System.out.println("You can crawl");
} else if (age == 1) {
    System.out.println("You can talk");
} else {
    System.out.println("You can walk");
}
```

If you really want to utilize branching `if` statements, the statements really have to branch, i.e. you have to properly nest the brackets:

```
if (age == 0) { 
    System.out.println("You can crawl");
} else {
    if (age == 1) {
        System.out.println("You can talk");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You can walk");
    }
}
```

Using an editor that actually formats code for you with proper indentation can help here.